# Trouble with a select case statement, need to avoid division by 0

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, case

I am using `Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1617.0 (64-bit)`
I have a table that keeps track of all users, time, and rows modified during a session on an excel file. My table(*named:* ***log***) originally looks like this:

```
Opened                  Closed                  Operator        Rows    Mins 
2013-06-26 11:53:58.000 2013-06-26 13:00:55.000 excel-user      225     67
2013-06-26 13:36:32.000 2013-06-26 15:58:25.000 excel-user      473     142
2013-06-26 16:17:34.000 2013-06-26 17:03:08.000 excel-user      181     46
```

I have wrote a simple query to calculate `Rows per Minute`. This is my query that does the job:

```
Select opened As 'Opened',
        closed As 'Closed',
        operator As 'Operator', 
        rows As 'Rows', 
        DATEDIFF(MI, opened, closed) As 'Mins',
        Convert( decimal(10,1), rows/Cast(DATEDIFF(MI, opened, closed) as decimal)) as 'Rows/Min'
from log
```

A problem arises in case when somebody opens the file for less than a minute. the number of mins then is equal to 0, therefore my current query fails giving a `divide by 0` error 
`Divide by zero error encountered.`

I have tried to use the Query Designer but I think my case is too complicated for it or I haven't properly explored the possibilities of the Query Designer. Anyhow, I think the way to go about it is to **omit calculations when any database entry (line) in the `Mins` column is equal to 0**. I have tried adding a `where mins <> 0` operator, however that just skips the rows and shows incomplete results => which is **not** what I am looking for. I have looked through SO and uncle google however I am still unable to solve this problem. I think I get the idea I just can't apply it within my case. I wouldn't have any trouble with such simple statement in C# or VB, however SQL is not my strong side so I need your help.
I have tried this query

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN rows <> 0 
        THEN 
            (
            SELECT 
                opened As 'Opened',
                closed As 'Closed',
                operator As 'Operator', 
                rows As 'Rows', 
                DATEDIFF(MI, opened, closed) As 'Mins',
                Convert( decimal(10,1), rows/Cast(DATEDIFF(MI, opened, closed)as decimal)) as 'Rows/Min'
            )
        ELSE 
            (
            SELECT
                opened As 'Opened',
                closed As 'Closed',
                operator As 'Operator', 
                rows As 'Rows', 
                DATEDIFF(MI, opened, closed) As 'Mins',
                '0' as 'Rows/Min'
            )
    END
FROM log
```

but it's giving me this error msg

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
>   subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
>   
>   I think this goes just a bit too far beyond my current knowledge of SQL queries so I would really appreciate your assistance. A good solution will obviously be rewarded with a check mark and upvote!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CASE statement is for one column only, it's not quite the same as an IF statement.

```
SELECT  opened As 'Opened',
        closed As 'Closed',
        operator As 'Operator', 
        [rows] As 'Rows', 
        DATEDIFF(MI, opened, closed) As 'Mins',
        CASE    WHEN [Rows] <> 0 
                THEN Convert( decimal(10,1), rows/Cast(DATEDIFF(MI, opened, closed) as decimal))
                ELSE 0
        END as 'Rows/Min'
FROM log
```

Comment: it does make perfect sense now. Thank you very much for pointing it out. +1 great job